# Database design adding multiple item

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am designing a database using MySQL Workbench for a clinic where each patient can see multiple doctors in each visit.

The table of patient is:

```
patient_id

patient_name

patient_address

patient_phone
```

The visit table:

```
visit_id

patient_id

doctor_id

visit_result

medicament_id
```

The problem is sometimes the patient in each visit may take multiple medicament in a prescription.

How can I incorporate this in the design ?

I tried to add all the medicament in the same line:

> Per example: 1, 4, 34.

But I can't do an SQL query later to see how many patient were given the medicament of the respective ID.

And the same thing if the patient saw multiple doctors in the same visit.

Extra info:

**medicament_table:**

```
medicament_id

medicament_name

medicament_expiry

medicament_quantity
```

Comment: Technically you can query using mySQL's [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function if you combine the data in a set field.  However, DON'T do it.  Instead create an associative/junction table   The question then becomes what is the key on visit table?  as that key needs to be part of the visitMedicaments table along with the medicament_ID

Comment: Your google search string is `many to many relationships`.

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: Can I make an associative join for the 3 tables (visit, medicament, doctor) so it would be like: associative_join(visit_id, med_id, doctor_id, auto_inc_id) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a join table between visits and medicaments that will tell you which meds were prescribed during which visit.

```
visit_id
medicament_id
```

As for multiple doctors per visit, perhaps a visit date would suffice. Other than that, you can introduce a concept of a "clinic visit" where you could aggregate multiple doctor appointments.

Comment: Personally I'd also indicate which doctor prescribed each medicament.

Comment: In the op, the there's a 1:1 relation between visits and doctors, so it will be possible to extract that with a join.

Comment: And when a doctor prescribe 3 medicaments...3 rows will be added to the join table right  So it is many to many relation ?

Comment: I mean that when i need to run sql query to insert all data, should i run 3 queries for each of 3 medicaments prescribed ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to add 3 rows, either with one or multiple inserts

Comment: Can I make an associative join for the 3 tables (visit, medicament, doctor) so it would be like: associative_join(visit_id, med_id, doctor_id, auto_inc_id) ?